# How to reuse a DOM node across React re-renders?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on integrating a third-party video recording library into my React application. This third-party package integrates directly into a DOM `<video>` element and has it's own state in such a way that state updates in my component *must not* cause a re-render of the `<video>` tag, as that will break the integration. I tried a naive approach like this:

`{this.videoNode.current || <video ref={this.videoNode} playsInline className="video-js vjs-default-skin"></video>}`

But it only causes React to complain with this error when a re-render was triggered:

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLVideoElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Is there a clean and simple way to do this without having to instantiate that `<video>` node in the raw HTML outside React?

Comment: Are you seeing the `<video>` tag get destroyed and recreated if you just render a `<video>` with no tricks? React doesn't unmount and remount components on a whim, so if you're seeing it do so, there's probably something weird about the stuff you're doing around the video tag.

Comment: Removing the trick seems to be working, but i'm wondering if there's a way to explicitly guarantee that the same node will always be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React reuses the existing dom elements where it can, so as long as you avoid some things that might force a remount you shouldn't need to do any trickery and just render a `<video>` tag normally.

Things that can cause problems:

1) React assumes that components with different types are a new subtree. So if you did something like this, then the change from `div` to `span` would cause the video element to remount:

```
const Example = () => {
  const [withDiv, setWithDiv] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setWithDiv(false), 5000);
  }, []);

  if (withDiv) {
    return (
      <div><video/></div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <span><video/></div>
    );

  }
}
```

2) `key` is a special property that can be used to inform react that two components are or are not the same component from one render to another. If the key changes, the component will remount, even if they might otherwise look the same. So the following case will cause the video player to remount:

```
const Example = () => {
  const [key, setKey] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setKey(2), 5000);
  }, []);

  return (
   <div key={key}><video/></div>
  )
}
```

But for most other cases, this shouldn't be a problem. The first time you render, a `<video>` element will be added to the dom, and then on subsequent renders that element will be reused.

For more information, see react's [documentation on reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#the-diffing-algorithm)